# Installer Projects extension Remove Previous Version

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2015, installation

I use the Installer Projects extension for visual studio 2015 to distribute my sw written in WPF.
I would like the installer, before the installation, remove all the files in the program folder.
I tried putting true RemovePreviousVersion properties but does not work.

Does anyone know how to fix?

Answer (score 0):

You have to make sure that ALL your project versions inside AssemblyInfo is altered to a new one (greater than the previous one) and also, check that the Installer version it self is altered and a new id is generated (be carefull not to alter the installer id but the upgrade id). It should prompt you when changing the version of the installer that new id will be generated.

Also, because the installer projects are no longer supported directly (see [wix](http://wixtoolset.org/)), a lot of issues may be raised by the vs extension.
Ypu may also try the [Inno setup](http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php). It very powerfull and easy to migrate from clasic installer projects.
Good luck.

Comment: Thank you for the reply.
In fact, I realized that the only file that fails to update is the appname.exe.config file.
Any idea why?

Comment: The configuration files are NEVER being altered during the runtime of windows installer. There are many ways to deal with this. You can create custom installer action (exec a bat file), or find a logic to change config contents upon application start-up. This is what I usually do: I add a new file to my installer project that will be copied to the root application directory and upon starting my application I check the existence of that file, if it exists, I do some special work and then delete it. if doesn't exist, I do nothing. Be careful to use encrypted file contents only for safety.